# Zimbra and cross-origin framing

Tags: nginx, zimbra, cors

Let's say that I have a Zimbra webmail accessible at `https://mail.example.com`. I also have a web app at `https://app.example.com`. On one of the app's pages I am trying to embed the webmail:

```
<iframe src="https://mail.example.com"></iframe>
```

However, when I go to the app page I get the following error (Firefox): `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://mail.example.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing`.

How can I enable cross-origin framing on Zimbra server/nginx (preferably only for app.example.com)? Or is it possible to embed webmail in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit:

/opt/zimbra/jetty/etc/zimbra.web.xml.in

Modify the Set Header Filter. Look for:

```
<filter-name>Set Header Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.zimbra.webClient.filters.SetHeaderFilter</filter-class>
```

section and add the following parameters:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>allowInFrame</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Just after that and restart Zimbra with:

```
zmcontrol restart
```

The downside is that you need to check if these modifications are still there on every update you do on the Zimbra software.